# Object doesn't support property or method 'delete' ie11 (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, internet-explorer-11

```
add() {

      if (this.state.password.length == 0) {
        this.props.dispatch(ShowAlert('warning','Please enter password',false,false))
        return;
      }
      let obj = this.props.fileToSend
      obj.delete('password')
      obj.append('password',this.state.password)
      console.log(obj)
      this.props.dispatch(SendFile(obj))

    //  this.props.close();
    }
```

I need delete field password and append new before I will send file to server, in all browsers work OK, except IE11. What hack I can use for this ?
file I created like

```
let fd = new FormData();
```

Comment: There is no native `obj.delete()` in the Object prototype

Comment: I know this, but how to resolve?

Comment: use the `delete` keyword

Comment: ?? what you mean

Answer (score 2):

The `FormData.delete` method is not supported in Internet Explorer ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete)). 
The only way to delete an entry from a `FormData` object is to create a new instance and copy all key/values over except the ones you want to delete.

Sadly Internet Explorer also doesn't support any of the `FormData.entries()`, `FormData.keys()` and other accessor methods. This means you'll have to manually store the values in a seperate object to be able to recreate the `FormData` object.

Answer (score 0):

Not as clean but there are two options.

You could override the `obj.password` value to be null.

Alternatively, you could create a new object from the existing data and omit the password property.

I.e:

```
var newObj = {
   prop1: obj.prop1,
   prop2: obj.prop2,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is trying to mutate this.props.fileToSend which it must not be mutated instead you should do something like that:

```
 const { password } =  this.state;
 const obj = { ...this.props.fileToSend, password };
 this.props.dispatch(SendFile(obj));
```